# SQL Azure Performance Concerns

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database

We are in the process of considering migrating from a virtual machine with Sql Server web edition to Sql Azure however some very basic (and I mean basic) tests have me a little concerned about the performance.  I created a DB locally and inserted 10000 rows and it took a few ms, when I connected to a basic Sql Azure database and ran a while loop to insert 10000 rows it took 2 minutes and 20 seconds.  I upgraded the database to Standard 2 (S2) and it completed in 40 seconds.  I then inserted 100k rows locally and it completed in 3 seconds, on S2 it took 6 minutes and 41 seconds.

I understand this is incredibly basic testing but it certainly concerns me about the performance of Sql Azure.  We currently have a virtual machine with 8 cores and 56gb ram (Azure VM D13) hosting around 10 database.  We want to move so we no longer have to worry about managing a Sql Server Virtual Machine.

Having read through this a few times:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741336.aspx

[image]

The way they are working out these values is completely beyond me, for example S2 says 2570 transactions per minute but I inserted 100k rows in 6 minutes.

This is the loop I was using to test:

```
DECLARE @cnt int = 100000
WHILE (@cnt > 0)
BEGIN

declare @seed int;
declare @string varchar(256);

select @seed = @cnt; -- saved start seed

exec GetRandomString @maxlen=50,
@seed = @seed output
, @string = @string output;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO Users VALUES (@string)

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SET @cnt = @cnt - 1;

END
```

Comment: Do you have a real scenario where you would insert rows that way? SQL Azure is generally slower but for 95% of real use cases is fast enough.

Comment: During the migration of our application we have a script which bulk inserts all the globalization values as we have a master sheet we maintain, this clears the existing table and inserts approx 6000 records.  This will significantly slow down our migration.

Comment: Did you manage to increase your throughput?
We can see that it takes like 30+ sec on S1 (~16 sec on S3) to bulk insert (BCP) of 1K rows.